# Make divs overflow and allow horizontal scroll (dynamic amount of divs)

Tags: html, css

This is an example of my current code:

```css
.parent div{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>  
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

As you can see they go below each other. I know I can wrap them in a div with a 100000px width but I don't want it to be white space, I want the user to be able to scroll up to the last item and that's it. Is there a way to do this without involving JS?

Comment: white-space:nowrap on the parent?

Comment: ```white-space: nowrap;``` keeps it in one line. But i'm confused on the question since he's saying he wants the user to scroll up to the last item. Meaning a column?

Comment: Yeah white-space nowrap did it, sorry for confusion, english is not my first language :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably many ways to do that - I would use flexbox which creates a row by default and then can overflow the parent and set the flex-basis to 200px on the divs.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.parent div{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  
  flex: 1 0 200px; // grow but not shrink, 200px basis
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>  
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The difference here is that you get the scroll bar on the parent element, not the page